# how ot initialized propertiesArray as an array

Tags: angular

Error: src/app/services/trades.service.ts:18:32 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Object'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Object'.

```
18           propertiesArray.push(data[id]);

getAllProperties(){
return this.http.get('data/properties.json').pipe(
  map(data => {
    const propertiesArray: Array<any> = [];
    for (const id in data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(id)){


      propertiesArray.push(data[id]);


    }
    }
    return propertiesArray;
  })
);
```

}

Comment: Could you please post an example content of `data/properties.json`?

Comment: what are you trying to do?
Maybe you are looking for Object.keys() instead? `map(data => Object.keys(data))`

Comment: [
  {
  "Id":1,
  "Name":"Jose",
  "Job":"Barber",
  "Salary":1000
  },
  {
    "Id":2,
    "Name":"Andres",
    "Job":"Barber",
    "Salary":1000
  },
  {
    "Id":3,
    "Name":"Juan",
    "Job":"Barber",
    "Salary":1000
  },
  {
    "Id":4,
    "Name":"Pablo",
    "Job":"Barber",
    "Salary":1000
  },
  {
    "Id":5,
  "Name":"Pedro",
  "Job":"Barber",
  "Salary":1000
  },
  {
    "Id":6,
    "Name":"Marcelo",
    "Job":"Barber",
    "Salary":1000
  }

]

Comment: im trying to for these data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your data is allways in the same format you can write something like that

```js
// First you define your own interface (make sure its outside of your class)
export interface IProperties {
  Id: number;
  Name: string;
  Salary: number;
}

// Then you map your `data:any` to `data:IProperties[]`
public getAllProperties(): Observable<IProperties[]> {
    return this.http
      .get('data/properties.json')
      .pipe(
        map(data => data as IProperties[])
      );
}
```